# working of libraries

Tags: api, operating-system, libraries, system-calls

I have worked with **< iostream>** and other general c++ libraries. Other than that i have also worked with libraries like **< pthread.h>.**

Now, i have read that system calls which are **operating system dependent** allow an interface between libraries and functionality implementation on hardware. This is evident in the working of < pthread.h>  which we can use in Linux but not in Windows. My explaination for this is that inside the < pthread.h> functions are defined using UNIX **system calls** which will not be understood by Windows.

But < iostream> seems to work fine in both Linux and Windows. Now my question is that even
 < iostream>'s function will need to be defined in terms of system calls which are different for Windows and Linux, then how is it that **< iostream> works fine on both OS**.

PS: I know that according to my idea above, all libraries(i.e. APIs) will be divided according to operating systems or libraries will come in different forms for different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

`<iostream>` is part of the C++ standard which provides users an interface so that you can run the same C++ code on different operating systems although they are implemented with different system calls underneath.

`<pthreads>` is part of the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) (Portable Operating System Interface) standard with a similar aim for implementing multithreaded applications.

So far so good.. Now the tricky part is that windows doesn't seem to support `pthreads` as well as most of the other POSIX standards because.. well, it's unconventional. It has its own threading library something like `win32-threads` instead.

Regarding operating systems, I guess it's fair to divide them into two classes namely windows and other unix-like operating systems (linux, macos, solaris etc.). That's not to say that windows is an evil operating system it's just that they have different goals.

If you need a portable multithreaded application you may want to use an higher level library such as [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) (which is implemented using `pthreads` in Linux and probably something like `win32-threads` in windows) or [Intel TBB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Threading_Building_Blocks) and so on.

Also [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) will have it's own built-in threading support which you can safely use in the same way in windows and others assuming those C++ compilers will be fully standard compliant.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, there are some projects aiming to implement POSIX standards on windows such as [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) or [Interix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interix) (developed by microsoft but deprecated in windows 8). If you want to use `<pthreads>` in windows you can use these as well. Threading calls you made using `<pthreads>` functions will be mapped to native windows threads.

Comment: @gokcehan...so please correct me if i am wrong...(1) C++ standard libraries like < iostream> have two sets of definition for each function.One set defines function using Windows system calls and other set defines function using Unix-like OS system calls.The set to be executed is determined by compiler based on the OS on which it is running...(2)pthreads and other posix libraries have only one set of definitions which use unix system calls..(3)Cygwin or interix use same signatures of functions as pthreads but while defining them they include win32-threads and use its functions to define them.

Comment: (1) C++ library headers such as `<iostream>` are installed as part of the compiler installation, something like `gcc` on linux or `cl.exe` (visual studio compiler) on windows.  Since `gcc` doesn't support windows (at least not natively -- see [mingw](http://mingw.org/) if you wanna get confused even more) and vica versa, there are no system calls for windows in `<iostream>` header file which exist on a linux system (checked this on my computer). (2) yes, if you exclude cygwin and interix

Comment: (3) I'm guessing yes (can't check since I don't have them installed) (4) things are not always black and white therefore a loose understanding will most likely be sufficient for most purposes unless you're a kernel hacker.